# How to handle event of UWP CalendarView's month (by next, previous button), year and decades change?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to get the current selected month on UWP **CalenderView** control. I can change month by Next/Previous button, month view and decades view. Is there any built-in event available for this?

Comment: This reply may [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180122/7254781).

Comment: Thanks Nico. I managed to get the months by DateTime AddMonths method. Disabled the decade selection and only allowed to do next/prev button navigation. So I can do the month calculation and manually setting the day first as selected date for the navigated month. For now I satisfied with the requirement. I hope MS will add the event for month change listener.

Comment: If you want month change listener please feel free post your request in [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).